# Unable to install python-gtk2 because of dependensies

Tags: apt, python

```
    (Reading database ... 215530 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python-gtk2 (2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2) over (2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-gtk2:
 python-gtk2 depends on python (<< 2.8); however:
  Package python is not installed.
 python-gtk2 depends on python (>= 2.7); however:
  Package python is not installed.
 python-gtk2 depends on python:any (>= 2.6.6-7~).

dpkg: error processing package python-gtk2 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

Hey. I am trying to install python-gtk2 but getting this error. I got all python2 and python3 versions installed but still getting this error. Any idea to fix? Thank in advance

Comment: Python2 has reached out of support in the beginning of 2020. These packages are not maintained anymore.

Comment: What happens when you run `sudo apt install python2.7`?